# Using bound function in AngularJS directive in the link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive and it looks like this :

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        getl: '&'
    },
    template: function()
    {
        return '<div data-ng-click="load_page(1)"></div>';
    },
    link: function(scope)
    {
        scope.current_page = 1;

        scope.load_page = function(increment)
        {
            scope.current_page += increment;

            scope.getl(scope.current_page);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm calling this directive like this:

```
<pager list="events" max="max_page" getl="get_events()"></pager>
```

What I'd like to do is being able to call the "getl" function from the "link" function of my directive but when I do so, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'f_get_events' in 2
```

I guess I'm missing something here but the only examples I found on Google were using the function in the template and I'd rather not to do like this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

- Your template is a broken string because you are using a single quote after load_page and no closing single string after the closing div:

  `template: function()
  {
      return '<div data-ng-click="load_page()'></div>;
  },`
- You can call scope methods in directives like this:

  - Pass in a parameter to the get_events() call: `<pager list="events" max="max_page" getl="get_events( currentPage )"></pager>`
  - Then use the parameter in the directive code by passing in an object with a property which corresponds to the parameter name:

  `scope.load_page = function(increment) {
  scope.current_page += increment;
  scope.getl({ currentPage: scope.current_page });
  }`

The type error you have given is hard to interpret, because it is hard to know if it is just because of the template string issue I described above, or something else.

Comment: Sorry, I edited a bit the code while I was posting the question, so the missing " was because of that. However, you answered my question thanks to the "{currentPage: scope.current_page}". I just tested and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it

Answer (score 1):

First thing your `template` function is missing `"` that may not be the problem but you should fix it, also your `load_page` is expecting `increment` parameter. As you passed nothing from `ng-click` function while calling `load_page` method, this line `scope.current_page += increment;` the value of current page becomes `undefined` because `1 + undefined = undefined`

```
template: function()
{
    return '<div data-ng-click="load_page(1)"></div>';
},
```

**Controller**

```
scope.load_page = function(increment) {
    scope.current_page += increment;
    scope.getl({ curPage: scope.current_page});
}
```

**Markup**

```
<pager list="events" max="max_page" getl="get_events(curPage)"></pager>
```